# How do I create a simple WSDL?

Tags: java, xml, wsdl

I'm new to WSDLs so I'm trying to create a simple math service with one. The service should add two integers together, as well as multiply two floats together, and return the results. I really don't even know where to start - is there any site etc. that has a good explanation of how to work with WSDLs, or could anyone give the runover on how a WSDL is constructed? I've read W3 Schools' explanation, but it was a bit brief.

Comment: Isn't "simple WSDL" an oxymoron?

Comment: Also, you can find [conceptual documentation on WSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996486.aspx) on MSDN. This should go more in-depth than W3Schools.

Comment: In most cases, you create the service, and the platform creates the WSDL for you. What platform are you using? Java, .NET?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm using Java. If I'm understanding correctly, you mean to say I can just create a simple class file in java that does the math operations I mentioned then I can generate a WSDL file from that? If that's the case, how would I go about generating the WSDL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSDL stands for Web Services Description Language. You can take a look at W3School documentation, it is pretty complete. http://www.w3schools.com/wsdl/wsdl_intro.asp. Usually the technology you use with to create your service, creates common mechanisms to handle the WSDL.Yo can see your WSDL adding this to your Web Service EndPoint.
?WSDL

Answer (score 0):

@Inerdia - +1 !  I wrote a WSDL for a service by hand, and it took a lot of blood, sweat and tears to get it right.  I *strongly* recommend using some kind of toolset to help you - either .NET dev environment or Apache Axis, or something of that sort.